# Switching keyboard in InputMethodService display a too large new keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm trying to implement a custom keyboard with the KeyboardView and InputMethodService.

I'd like to have a button that switch my keyboard to have a letters keyboard or a special characters keyboard.

But when I switch keyboard, the width of my second keyboard is always expanded and doesnt fit width screen.

So i create two xml files

First is my letters keyboard (keys_layout.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="4dp"
    android:keyHeight="60dp"
    android:verticalGap="4dp"
    >
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2"/>
        <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3"/>
        <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4"/>
        <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5"/>
        <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6"/>
        <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7"/>
        <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8"/>
        <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9"/>
        <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="0" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="97" android:keyLabel="a" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="122" android:keyLabel="z"/>
        <Key android:codes="101" android:keyLabel="e"/>
        <Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="r"/>
        <Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="t"/>
        <Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="y"/>
        <Key android:codes="117" android:keyLabel="u"/>
        <Key android:codes="105" android:keyLabel="i"/>
        <Key android:codes="111" android:keyLabel="o"/>
        <Key android:codes="112" android:keyLabel="p"/>
        <Key android:codes="-5"  android:keyIcon="@drawable/baseline_backspace_24" android:isRepeatable="true" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="113" android:keyLabel="q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="115" android:keyLabel="s"/>
        <Key android:codes="100" android:keyLabel="d"/>
        <Key android:codes="102" android:keyLabel="f"/>
        <Key android:codes="103" android:keyLabel="g"/>
        <Key android:codes="104" android:keyLabel="h"/>
        <Key android:codes="106" android:keyLabel="j"/>
        <Key android:codes="107" android:keyLabel="k"/>
        <Key android:codes="108" android:keyLabel="l"/>
        <Key android:codes="109" android:keyLabel="m"/>
        <Key android:codes="-4" android:keyIcon="@drawable/baseline_keyboard_return_24" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
<!--        <Key android:codes="35,64" android:keyLabel="\# \@" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>-->
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="-1" android:isModifier="true" android:keyIcon="@drawable/shift_outlined" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w"/>
        <Key android:codes="120" android:keyLabel="x"/>
        <Key android:codes="99" android:keyLabel="c"/>
        <Key android:codes="118" android:keyLabel="v"/>
        <Key android:codes="98" android:keyLabel="b"/>
        <Key android:codes="110" android:keyLabel="n"/>
        <Key android:codes="63" android:keyLabel="\?"/>
        <Key android:codes="44" android:keyLabel=","/>
        <Key android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="."/>
        <Key android:codes="-1" android:isModifier="true" android:keyIcon="@drawable/shift_outlined" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
        <!-- <Key android:codes="63,33,58" android:keyLabel="\? ! :" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/> -->
<!--        <Key android:codes="47" android:keyLabel="/" android:keyWidth="10%p" />-->
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="1339" android:isModifier="true" android:keyLabel="!#1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="1340" android:keyLabel="@string/key_label_mc_do"/>
        <Key android:codes="32" android:keyLabel="SPACE" android:keyWidth="60%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
        <Key android:codes="1341" android:keyIcon="@drawable/baseline_keyboard_arrow_left_24" />
        <Key android:codes="1342" android:keyIcon="@drawable/baseline_keyboard_arrow_right_24" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

then it's my specials characters layout (keys_special_characters_layout.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="4dp"
    android:keyHeight="60dp"
    android:verticalGap="4dp"
    >
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2"/>
        <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3"/>
        <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4"/>
        <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5"/>
        <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6"/>
        <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7"/>
        <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8"/>
        <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9"/>
        <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="0" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="43" android:keyLabel="+" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="120" android:keyLabel="x"/>
        <Key android:codes="247" android:keyLabel="÷"/>
        <Key android:codes="61" android:keyLabel="="/>
        <Key android:codes="47" android:keyLabel="/"/>
        <Key android:codes="95" android:keyLabel="_"/>
        <Key android:codes="36" android:keyLabel="€"/>
        <Key android:codes="156" android:keyLabel="£"/>
        <Key android:codes="165" android:keyLabel="¥"/>
        <Key android:codes="8361" android:keyLabel="₩"/>
        <Key android:codes="-5"  android:keyIcon="@drawable/baseline_backspace_24" android:isRepeatable="true" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="64" android:keyLabel="@string/key_arobase" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="35" android:keyLabel="#"/>
        <Key android:codes="36" android:keyLabel="$"/>
        <Key android:codes="37" android:keyLabel="%"/>
        <Key android:codes="94" android:keyLabel="^"/>
        <Key android:codes="38" android:keyLabel="@string/key_ampersand"/>
        <Key android:codes="42" android:keyLabel="*"/>
        <Key android:codes="40" android:keyLabel="("/>
        <Key android:codes="41" android:keyLabel=")"/>
        <Key android:codes="-4" android:keyIcon="@drawable/baseline_keyboard_return_24" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="-1" android:isModifier="true" android:keyIcon="@drawable/shift_outlined" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="45" android:keyLabel="-"/>
        <Key android:codes="39" android:keyLabel="'"/>
        <Key android:codes="34" android:keyLabel="@string/key_quote"/>
        <Key android:codes="58" android:keyLabel=":"/>
        <Key android:codes="59" android:keyLabel=";"/>
        <Key android:codes="33" android:keyLabel="!"/>
        <Key android:codes="63" android:keyLabel="\?"/>
        <Key android:codes="44" android:keyLabel=","/>
        <Key android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="."/>
        <Key android:codes="-1" android:isModifier="true" android:keyIcon="@drawable/shift_outlined" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="1339" android:isModifier="true" android:keyLabel="ABC" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="1340" android:keyLabel="@string/key_label_mc_do"/>
        <Key android:codes="32" android:keyLabel="SPACE" android:keyWidth="60%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
        <Key android:codes="1341" android:keyIcon="@drawable/baseline_keyboard_arrow_left_24" />
        <Key android:codes="1342" android:keyIcon="@drawable/baseline_keyboard_arrow_right_24" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

then in my InputMethodService, I define keyboard like this :

```
private var keyboardView: KeyboardView? = null
    private var currentKeyboard: Keyboard? = null
    private var letterKeyboard: Keyboard? = null
    private var specialCharKeyboard: Keyboard? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        letterKeyboard = Keyboard(this, R.xml.keys_layout)
        specialCharKeyboard = Keyboard(this, R.xml.keys_special_characters_layout)
        currentKeyboard = letterKeyboard
    }

    override fun onCreateInputView(): View {
        keyboardView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.keyboard_view, null) as KeyboardView
        keyboardView?.keyboard = currentKeyboard
        keyboardView?.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this)
        keyboardView?.isPreviewEnabled = false
        return keyboardView!!
    }

    override fun onKey(primaryCode: Int, keyCodes: IntArray) {
         SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_KEY_CODE -> {
                    toggleKeyboard()
                }
    }

     private fun toggleKeyboard() {
        currentKeyboard = if (currentKeyboard === letterKeyboard) {
            specialCharKeyboard
        } else {
            letterKeyboard
        }
        keyboardView?.keyboard = currentKeyboard
    }
```

the switching is fine but my keyboard is way too large when i switch to a new keyboard like the screenshots below :

[Letters keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yISt1.png)

[Special Characters Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gofuu.png)

Any ideas why and how i can fix that ?

Thanks a lot in advance and have a good day !